# How to do a Bayesian survival analysis and determine which variables are useful?

Tags: bayesian, survival

I can measure two variables on each patient in a survival study (I have the measurements and the survival times; some patients outlive the study and are therefore censored). I know that it is possible to use either of these variables to assign patients to groups with different survival curves (using a simple threshold on the variables). What I want to know is whether using both variables allows me to assign patients better than just one of the variables — i.e., whether the survival characteristics are more different when both variables are included; whether a given variable provides information that the other one doesn't.

I would prefer to do this in a Bayesian manner using JAGS (BUGS); I tend to find these models easier to understand.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without further details about your model, priors and etcetera, the best thing I can do is to point out a reference for Bayesian variable selection

> Faraggi and Simon (1998). [Bayesian Variable Selection Method for Censored Survival Data](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2533672). *Biometrics* Vol. 54, No. 4, pp. 1475-1485.

Of course, the typical way for conducting Bayesian model selection is the use of Bayes factors `(http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~kass/papers/bayesfactors.pdf)`. You can use the posterior simulations obtained with your favourite software to calculate the Bayes factors using an importance sampling as detailed in

> Chopin and Robert (2010). [Properties of Nested Sampling](http://arxiv.org/abs/0801.3887). *Biometrika* 97 (3): 741-755.